# Java send email bot Custom message with JOptionPane

Tags: java, email, joptionpane

I'm not a very experienced coder, but I have been learning. Right now I am in the process of writing a test email bot to, well, send emails. I ran across a problem when I tried to make it so you could type out the message and subject of the email in a JOptionPane Dialog box.

Here is the code, look at the Strings at the top and the messageobjs at the bottom..

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ebot2 
{


   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

      String Dest;
      Dest = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Who would you like to message?");

      String Subject;
      Subject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the message subject?");

      String Message;
      Message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the message?");




      String sendrmailid = "email@gmail.com";
      final String uname = "email";
      final String pwd = "pass";

      Properties propvls = new Properties();
      propvls.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      propvls.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      propvls.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      propvls.put("mail.smpt.port", "25");

      Session sessionobj = Session.getInstance(propvls,
         new javax.mail.Authenticator()
         {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
               return new PasswordAuthentication(uname, pwd);
            }
         });

      try 
      {
         Message messageobj = new MimeMessage(sessionobj);
         messageobj.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sendrmailid));
                                                                                              messageobj.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(Dest));
     messageobj.setSubject(Subject);
     messageobj.setText(Message);

     Transport.send(messageobj);
     System.out.println("Your email sent successfully....");
  } 
  catch (MessagingException exp) 
  {
     throw new RuntimeException(exp);
  }
 }
}
```

sorry for the shit formatting, the code block thing was difficult. Anyways the error Im getting started, after I changed the setSubject and setText to Strings that are entered through a JOptionPane. And the error is..

```
Ebot2.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
          messageobj.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(Dest));
                                    ^
symbol:   variable RecipientType
location: variable Message of type String
1 error
```

Thanks to anyone who answers, I really need help on this!

Comment: Check your imports? Message is missing

Comment: Add `import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;`

Comment: I added java mail message recipienttype import, but it didn't really effect anything. Im still getting the same error. Keep in mind that before I added all the JOptionPane stuff for the message and subject area, the code worked perfectly fine.  Should I just take out the JOptionPane stuff for message and subject?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it guys. The problem was I had the String for the message set as Message (same problem with subject) which was also a variable. So I just renamed the string and it all worked. Thanks for the help anyways, glad to know I can go to this site for questions.

Next I'm going to try to figure out how to send the email multiple times, but I should be able to figure that out on my own.